# unable to write to json file in after each hook due to timeout issue in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have an 'afterEach' hook for each test. This will write some value to json.
The value for 'TestDetails' is available globally in in the test file.

```
afterEach(function () {                                    
    cy.readFile('cypress/dataFiles/data1.json').then(function (t1) {                                    
      t1["testDetails"] = testDetailsValue;
      cy.writeFile('cypress/dataFiles/data1.json', JSON.stringify(t1));                                    
  })
})
```

The first test is login test and launching the browser and navigating to login page takes more than 10 seconds.

When test is executed, the below error is displayed:

```
CypressError: `cy.readFile("cypress/dataFiles/data1.json")` timed out after waiting `4000ms`.

Because this error occurred during a `after each` hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite:
```

Due to this error, unable to write the value in json in after each hook.

Could anyone please help on this?

Comment: I don't see what is wrong. Is that really the whole error message? What's the content of `data1.json`. Try with empty json-object as content `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

I think that means that your file doesn't exist. See https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile#Existence

Comment: The file 'data1.json' is inside cypress/dataFiles/. Is the path format incorrect? How to sort this issue as the file exist but it's not locating the file.

Comment: Why don't you try other path formats?